# Rails group records by dates of created_at retrieve hash with date string as the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to retrieve records from a model and group them by dates *via* the `created_at` field.

My problem is that I am unsure how to get a hash with a date string as the key.
I am doing `Model.group('date(created_at)').count` which returns `{Sat, 19 Dec 2020=>9, Sun, 20 Dec 2020=>7}`

What I want is `{'2020-12-19'=>9, '2020-12-20'=>7}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast date to a [string](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/), otherwise rails will format date.

```
Model.group("to_char(date(created_at), 'yyyy-mm-dd')").count
```

This should give an output hash as you require